# Do we have a language policy?

Tags: discussion, language

I'm looking at [What is the temperature of the surface and core of a neutron star formed 12 billion years ago now equal to?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/519/what-now-is-the-surface-temperature-of-the-neutron-star-which-was-formed-12-bil): part of the question was asked in Russian, which is the first time I can recall seeing a non-English question on a Stack Exchange site. Should we do something about questions in other languages? Edit a translation into the body of the question, perhaps? (Assuming someone is confident enough in their language skills to do the translation) Or do we just leave them as they are?

Comment: One school of thought on this is to leave them as they are (unless there is someone capable of translating **and** preserving the intent of the questioner) **but** with the caveat that they are restricting their audience (severely?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is with respect to SO ([StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), the site that started the whole SE business), which we are not but since it works good there we should at least think about this:

Jeff Atwood [stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/add-meta-tag-to-support-internationalization/7320#7320) (regarding non-english posts on http://stackoverflow.com)

> I believe programmers who speak only Mandarin, or French, or Spanish, are better off forming their own communities and centers of gravity. Shared language is one of the fundamental aspects of community.
>
> Just visit Chinatown in nearby San Francisco to see what I mean..

After some digging I found [this blog post from '07](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) as a follow-up on the discussion [We need to help non-English-speakers somehow…](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/), and the faq-entry [Is English required on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/146482)

So, on SO the policy is:

> I say keep it in English. I'm not against diversity or other languages, I'm for us all being able to communicate under one. This isn't political, this isn't about smothering peoples cultures with Western ideologies. It is about being pragmatic.

I do agree that multiple languages on one site cause confusion. But we should not "ban" non-english speakers, so I suggest we do not vote on non-english posts (both questions and answers) and try to translate things to english as good as possible. As soon as the correctness of the translation is verified, the original text should be removed - it will still be available by clicking on the *edited by* link. Maybe one can edit in a
`[original version in russian](http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/519/revisions#rev3252802a-affc-499f-9316-3e44d8a4f81c)`
link or post that as comment, for example.